# How to convert year month and min information to day num

Tags: matlab

I want to convert the given year, month and min information to day of year info.

For eg lets say

year 2004, month 2, day 2 =  33rd day of year

how can I do it in matlab?

Answer (score 2):

Get the `datenum` for Jan 1 of that year, and subtract it from the given yy/mm/dd.  For example, today's day of the year:

```
jan1 = datenum(datestr(now,'yy'),'yy')
now - jan1 + 1
```

Check the above against [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/daynumbers.php).

For a specific date,

```
>> yy = 2004; mm = 2; dd = 2;
>> doty = datenum(yy,mm,dd) - datenum(yy,1,0)
doty =
    33
```